# Get DataGridView modified contents in Button click event

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` with a `ContextMenu`. The `ContextMenu` has *Insert Row, Insert Column, Delete Row* and *Delete Column* `MenuItem`s. The user can add/delete rows/columns in the click events of the `ContextMenu` `MenuItem`s.

Initially, the data displayed in the `DataGridView` is retrieved from a table in database.
Once the user completes editing the `DataGridView` content i.e., add/delete rows/columns, s/he clicks on *Save* `Button`.

Now in the `Button` click event, I have to update all the newly added/modified data back into the database. How?

Comment: What about your `DataSource`? It should be a `DataTable`, a `BindingSource` or a `DataView`. You can deal with the `DataSource` only without touching your `DataGridView`.

Comment: I don't have a `DataSource`. Using a `DataSource` was not compatible for me. I am adding the cell content by looping through the `DataTable` after retrieving from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use GetChanges() on your datatable.
It returns Datatable if any changes in your datatable.
Update that returned datatable to database throuhgh adapter

Answer (score 0):

You should maintain DataSet along with your datagridview.

1. Update the DataSet whenever Cell value changes in DataGridview
2. Add new row to DataSet when a row is added to DataGridView
3. And finally you can use DataAdapter's Update method to reflect all changes back to database

Comment: I have already mention in my comment above that I am not using `DataSource`. How do you suggest I maintain a `DataSet` along with `DataGridView`?

Comment: I have few fields in the `DataGridView` whose values are calculated based on other fields. All the data displayed is not from database.